# Plotting multiple plots into one pdf using ggplot

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I want to create a single pdf that includes a list of plots of each day separated into different months. Each page will designate a new month and will contain 30-31 plots signifying the days within that month.

It isn't the best, but I created a loop to loop through every month from 1998-2019 of my dataset. Originally I just used print(q) to add each set of graphs into a different page of the pdf, but the scaling was off. As of now, the only way I know how to properly scale the graphs is to use ggsave and manually setting the scaling options. The only problem is when I use ggsave, it overwrites the previous graph on the pdf.

Is there any way to plot multiple graphs onto different pages of one pdf using ggsave? Or is there any way to scale the set of graphs on each page when creating the plot itself?

```
monthCount = 6
yearCount = 1998
count = 1

dateList <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
              "September", "October", "November", "December")

while(count < 287){

  df <- as.data.frame(working.data %>% filter(date.year == yearCount, date.month == monthCount))

  q <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date.hour, y = SLP)) +  
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24, 1)) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(990, 1040))+
    facet_wrap( ~date.day, ncol = 6, nrow = 6) +
    facet_wrap(~date.day, nrow = 6, ncol = 6) +
    labs(x = "Hours", y = "Sea Level Pressure",
         title = paste("Hourly Pressure Readings:", dateList[c(monthCount)], yearCount, sep=" "))


  ggsave("testPlot.pdf", q, width = 7, height = 7, units = "in", scale = 4) 

  if(monthCount < 12){
    monthCount = monthCount + 1
  }else{
    monthCount = 1
    yearCount = yearCount + 1
  } 

  count = count + 1
}  

dev.off()
```

[Page of plots without scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzEcL.png)
;
[Page of plots with scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LiDH.png)

Comment: FYI, you can use the built-in `month.name` instead of defining your own `dateList`.

Comment: I would try putting the plots in an Rmarkdown document, and then you could use chunk options to adjust the scaling. It's hard to help more than that without a little bit of sample data. If you could share a few months from a couple years, (use `dput()` to make it copy/pasteable) we could try out some solutions.